# MakeFile not working?

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I have one Java file (example.java) and one Makefile, while trying to execute the Makefile with make command I am getting the below error:

**Makefile:5: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.**

Below is the content of my Makefile

```
CP=-cp .:/usr/share/java/log4j.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-core-
asl.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-mapper-
asl.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-
smile.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-
jaxrs.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-
mrbean.jar:/usr/share/java/jackson/jackson-
xc.jar:../../../lib/java/lib/alarm-logging-libs.jar
all: alarm_example.class

example.class: example.java
        javac -d . $(CP) example.java
clean:
        rm -fr *.class
```

Request you kindly have a look and provide your suggestion.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I suggest you don't use `make`. It's really not adequate for Java or modern systems, by which I mean most things built in the last 20+ years. Use `ant` or `Maven`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad error message. It either means that a character in your filenames could be part of a regular expression or that you should

> check the value of any variables in your target and prerequisite lists to be sure they do not contain colons.

You might find this useful (from the manual): [Errors Generated by Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html)

> If you see these errors and you aren’t trying to create a static pattern rule, check the value of any variables in your target and prerequisite lists to be sure they do not contain colons. See [Syntax of Static Pattern Rules.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage)